# What is $\lim_{x\to\infty}1^x$? Is this limit equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{2i\pi})^x$?

Tags: limits, infinity

It is easy to think that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}1^x$ is just $1$, but it isn't so obvious when you rewrite it as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{2i\pi})^x$.

$e^{2i\pi x}$ is $1$ whenever $x$ is an integer, but can be a complex number if $x$ is, say, $\frac13$. Since $e^{2i\pi}=1$, $e^{2i\pi x}$ *should* be equivalent to $1^x$, but we usually interpret $1^\frac13$ as $1$ and $e^{\frac23i\pi}$ as a nontrivial third root of unity. This raises some questions. When taking numbers to the power of an integer, there is always a single possible value, yet when taking numbers to the power of a non-integer, there are multiple possible values. How do we precisely define $x^y$ such that $x^y$ is a single value? Is exponentiation even a function which has a single output for each input?

Back to the original limit. We interpret $1^x$ to always be equal to $1$, so $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}1^x$ should just be $1$. However, $(e^{2i\pi})^x$ isn't always equal to $1$; as $x$ changes, when we graph the expression on the complex plane, the output spins around counterclockwise in a circle. We can't find the limit when $x$ approaches infinity because the expression clearly doesn't approach anything.

Now, if we restrict $x$ such that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can see that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{2i\pi})^x$ approaches $1$ as well as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}1^x$. How come $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{2i\pi})^x$ is defined when approaching infinity from the integers, but not when we approach it from the real numbers? How do we define infinity?

One way I came up with to define infinity is that it is the cardinality of a set $A$ such that a bijection exists between $A$ and one of $A$'s proper subsets. This definition implies that infinity is kind of like an *integer* that is larger than all other *integers*. However, under this definition, we may be able to interpret infinity to behave like an integer and conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{2i\pi})^x$ is just $1$.

What is the resolution to all of this confusion?

Comment: To avoid confusion, never write $x^y$. For instance, instead of $e^{2\pi ix}$ just write $\exp(2\pi ix)$. And what has "infinity" to do with any of this?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It's about evaluating the limits in the title.

Answer (score 4):

$(e^{2\pi i })^x$ *is* 1 for every $x \in \Bbb C$. The key point of your question is not about limits or infinity, but rather about the fact that exponential laws don't generally hold for complex numbers. $\left(a^b\right)^c \neq a^{bc}$ in general for complex $a,b,c$.